# updating div with jQuery and Knockout.js with .html() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This should be a simple matter of updating some simple modal controls with `.html()` but for some reason, I'm having issues. This is the modal code...

```
<div id="answerTaskQuestionModal" class=" modal-dialog" data-bind="with: currentQuestion">
    <div id="answerTaskQuestionValidation" class="validation"></div>
    <span data-bind="text: html"></span>
    <div id="taskQuestionAnswer"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript inside my working view model...

```
self.answerTaskQuestion = function (question) {
    $('#answerTaskQuestionValidation').html('');

    var $taskQuestionAnswer = $('#taskQuestionAnswer');

    $taskQuestionAnswer.html(' \* {my html with bindings} *\ ');

    $answerTaskQuestionModal.dialog('open');

    self.currentQuestion(question);
};
```

Basically, I'm trying to dynamically change the ways one can answer a question as a proof of concept. If I just paste the html inside the target `div`, they work. However, when I check the value of `.html()`, this is what happens...

first run: `$taskQuestionAnswer.html()` returns `undefined`

second run: `$taskQuestionAnswer.html()` returns the proper HTML but the `div` won't update.

Replacing the bindings with just simple HTML doesn't help either. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think after   `$taskQuestionAnswer.html(' \* {my html with bindings} *\ ');`
you should call `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel)` again to apply view model to new html.

Comment: As you can see in the question, no html value gets posted to the div, bindings or no bindings. I would still have the elements that would frame the bindings being created in the modal, it's just the bindings that would be missing. This is not the case. There's no update at all.